# Is there a get_account method in version 2.0 of the BOX.net API?

Tags: box-api

In version 1.0 of the BOX.net API, there's a method to get a user's account information (http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923928/ApiFunction_get_account_info)

```
https://www.box.net/api/1.0/rest?action=get_account_info&api_key=<key>&auth_token=<token>
```

But in version 2.0, I can't find an equivalent method.  Does it exist?  Or is the old method still available in some form using the new 2.0 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently have not yet implemented the /users endpoint which would provide the information you're looking for.

However, auth tokens will currently work across v1 and v2, so you can still call the v1 method.

Comment: I will use v1 for now but is there an ETA on the v2 support of the get user info method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
BoxClient client = getAuthenticatedClient(code);
BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject = null;
List<BoxUser> userList = client.getUsersManager().getAllEnterpriseUser(requestObject, null);
for (BoxUser usr : userList) {
    System.out.println("Addr: " + usr.getAddress());
    System.out.println("Name : " + usr.getName());
    System.out.println("Login : " + usr.getLogin());
}
```